# Sort list with multiple criteria and multiple variables in C#

Tags: c#, sorting

I am having an issue sorting some objects with certain criteria. I have searched but it seems like no one is doing it the way I am or maybe my situation is unique or I am doing it all wrong. I am trying to sort a few objects within visual studio via C#. I have several animal classes and a zoo class (interface) as well as a sorting class. In my main class I have the following where I make a list and try to sort the list of animals I made:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

            Lion aLion = new Lion("Leo", DateTime.Parse("4/04/2012"),
                2500, 360, 0, 9);
            Giraffe aGiraffe = new Giraffe("Amber", DateTime.Parse("3/23/2013"),
                4500, 1400, 0, 25);
            Giraffe aSecondGiraffe = new Giraffe("Charlie", DateTime.Parse("5/2/2012"),
                3600, 2600, 0, 25);
            Giraffe aThirdGiraffe = new Giraffe("George", DateTime.Parse("5/22/2013"),
                3000, 3200, 0, 3);
            Lion aThirdLion = new Lion("Charlie", DateTime.Parse("1/10/2011"),
                1000, 6, 0, 27);
            Lion aSecondLion = new Lion("Bernie", DateTime.Parse("1/30/2012"),
                1200, 8, 0, 27);
            Lion aFourthLion = new Lion("Billy", DateTime.Parse("12/12/2012"),
                5000, 350, 0, 20);
            Lion aFifthLion = new Lion("Jake", DateTime.Parse("10/15/2015"),
               10000, 400, 0, 20);
            Giraffe aFifthGiraffe = new Giraffe("Mike", DateTime.Parse("5/2/2016"),
                8000, 620, 0, 10);
            Giraffe aFourthGiraffe = new Giraffe("Joe", DateTime.Parse("5/17/2014"),
                8500, 645, 0, 10);


        List<IZoo> aZoo = new System.Collections.Generic.List<IZoo>();

        aZoo.Add(aLion);
        aZoo.Add(aGiraffe);
        aZoo.Add(aSecondGiraffe);
        aZoo.Add(aThirdGiraffe);
        aZoo.Add(aThirdLion);
        aZoo.Add(aSecondLion);
        aZoo.Add(aFourthLion);
        aZoo.Add(aFifthLion);
        aZoo.Add(aFifthGiraffe);
        aZoo.Add(aFourthGiraffe);


        string fileSpec = "LogData.txt";
        StreamWriter output = File.CreateText(fileSpec);

        var sortByPurchaseCost = new Class1.sortPurchaseCostAscendingHelper();
        aZoo.Sort(sortByPurchaseCost);
        Console.WriteLine(PrintReportHeader());
        foreach (IZoo animalData in aZoo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{animalData}");

        }
        Console.WriteLine(" ");

        var sortBysortWeightAndDOB = new Class1.sortWeightAndDOBHelper();
        aZoo.Sort(sortBysortWeightAndDOB);
        Console.WriteLine(PrintReportHeader());
        foreach (IZoo animalData in aZoo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{animalData}");

        }

        Console.WriteLine(" ");

        var sortCagePurchaseCostAnimalNameID = new Class1.sortCagePurchaseCostAnimalNameIDHelper();
        aZoo.Sort(sortCagePurchaseCostAnimalNameID);
        Console.WriteLine(PrintReportHeader());
        foreach (IZoo animalData in aZoo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{animalData}");

        }

        Console.WriteLine(" ");

        var sortAgeWeight = new Class1.sortAgeWeightHelper();
        aZoo.Sort(sortAgeWeight);
        Console.WriteLine(PrintReportHeader());
        foreach (IZoo animalData in aZoo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{animalData}");

        }

        Console.WriteLine(" ");

        var sortTypePCCageName = new Class1.sortTypePCCageNameHelper();
        aZoo.Sort(sortTypePCCageName);
        Console.WriteLine(PrintReportHeader());
        foreach (IZoo animalData in aZoo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{animalData}");

        }
        output.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress <ENTER> to quit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static string PrintReportHeader()
    {
        return $"{"ID",-7} {"Animal Type",-15} {"Name",-15} {"Weight",-8}" + 
            $"{"Age",-5} {"Purchase Cost",-16} {"Cage No.",-10}\n" + 
            $"{"==",-7} {"===========",-15} {"====",-15} {"======",-8}" + 
            $"{"===",-5} {"=============",-16} {"========",-10}"; }
```

In my sorting class I have the following:

```
public class sortPurchaseCostAscendingHelper : IComparer<IZoo>
    {
        public int Compare(IZoo z1, IZoo z2)
        {


            if (z1.PurchaseCost > z2.PurchaseCost)
                return 1;

            if (z1.PurchaseCost < z2.PurchaseCost)
                return -1;

            else
                return 0;
        }
    }

    public class sortWeightAndDOBHelper : IComparer<IZoo>
    {
        public int Compare(IZoo z1, IZoo z2)
        {

            if (z1.Weight > z2.Weight && z1.DOB > z2.DOB)
                return 1;

            if (z1.Weight < z2.Weight && z1.DOB < z2.DOB)
                return -1;

            else
                return 0;
        }

        public static implicit operator sortWeightAndDOBHelper(sortAgeWeightHelper v)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class sortCagePurchaseCostAnimalNameIDHelper : IComparer<IZoo>
    {
        public int Compare(IZoo z1, IZoo z2)
        {

            if (z1.CageNumber > z2.CageNumber && z1.PurchaseCost > z2.PurchaseCost && z1.Name > z2.Name && z1.ID > z2.ID)
                return 1;

            if (z1.Weight < z2.Weight && z1.DOB < z2.DOB)
                return -1;

            else
                return 0;
        }
    }

    public class sortAgeWeightHelper : IComparer<IZoo>
    {
        public int Compare(IZoo z1, IZoo z2)
        { 

            if (z1.DOB > z2.DOB && z1.Weight > z2.Weight)
                return 1;

            if (z1.DOB < z2.DOB && z1.Weight < z2.Weight)
                return -1;

            else
                return 0;
        }
    }

    public class sortTypePCCageNameHelper : IComparer<IZoo>
    {
        public int Compare(IZoo z1, IZoo z2)
        {

            if (z1.PurchaseCost > z2.PurchaseCost && z1.CageNumber > z2.CageNumber)
                return 1;

            if (z1.PurchaseCost < z2.PurchaseCost && z1.CageNumber < z2.CageNumber)
                return -1;

            else
                return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Each Icomparer needs to sort the five FOREACH sections differently. I am having trouble trying to link these Icomparers to my main FOREACH list in order to sort. If anyone has an idea for me or maybe a better way at going about this I am all ears. Thanks! Please feel free to ask more questions if you need anymore clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You can `sort()` before each `FOREACH` like below.

Change your `Helper` class to `public`, so it's accessible from `void Main()`, then write up your `Comparer` as below:

```
public class sortPurchaseCostAscendingHelper : IComparer<IZoo>
{
    public int Compare(IZoo z1, IZoo z2)
    {
        if (z1.PurchaseCost > z2.PurchaseCost)
            return 1;

        if (z1.PurchaseCost < z2.PurchaseCost)
            return -1;

        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Before each `FOREACH`, you call `sort()` with particular `Comparer` like this:

```
var sortByPurchaseCost = new sortPurchaseCostAscendingHelper();
        aZoo.Sort(sortByPurchaseCost);
        foreach (IZoo animalData in aZoo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{animalData}");

        }
```

You can do it for the rest of your comparers.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense but I am still getting an error on 
     aZoo.Sort(sortByPurchaseCost)  it says that I cannot convert from 'A2_Zoo_Sorts_BahlerArslan,Class1.sortPurchaseCostAscendingHelper" to "System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<A2_ZooSorts_BahlerArslan.IZoo>" any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show me your full code of it? Your `sortPurchaseCostAscendingHelper ` should inherit `IComparer<IZoo>`, not just `IComparer`

Comment: Okay I updated my code above to what I currently have. I fixed the original problem but for some reason It is still not sorting properly. Thank you for your help @zzT

Comment: It worked! I am a heavy Java programmer and I always forget to rebuild and clean my project when using Visual Studio. Rookie mistakes! Thanks again @zzT

Comment: OK, dear. Seems like someone also interested in your problem, you can mark my answer as final answer, or update your code in your question, so it helps our community. Thanks.